# HTML5 Canvas - Why the color of the rectangle always returns black?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, random

I want to draw a canvas rectangle that changes color every load. Here is my code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var can = document.getElementById("lol");
    var ctx = can.getContext("2d");
    var colors = ["rgba(255,0,0,1)", "rgba(0,255,0,1)", "rgba(0,0,255,1)"];

    ctx.fillStyle = colors[Math.random() * 3];
    ctx.fillRect(40,40,30,25);
}
```

Yet, every time when i open a web page, The color should changed to either red, blue or green but the color is persistently black.

**Why is this happens? What is wrong in my code?**

Comment: your random routine rarely returns an integer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not picking the random number correctly. Your random function will hardly ever return an integer.

[Read more about Math.random here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Here is what you're trying to do:

```js
var can = document.getElementById("lol");
var ctx = can.getContext("2d");
var colors = ["rgba(255,0,0,1)", "rgba(0,255,0,1)", "rgba(0,0,255,1)"];

ctx.fillStyle = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
ctx.fillRect(40,40,30,25);
```

```html
<canvas id="lol"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to take an integer value for accessing an array element.

```
ctx.fillStyle = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
```

I suggest to use the length of the array as factor for the random number (a constant vaue may go wrong if the count of elements changes later).

```
ctx.fillStyle = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `ctx.fillStyle = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];`
https://jsfiddle.net/xpavwkod/